# Impossible to edit in responsive design mode

Tags: bug, editing

When editing a [Late Answer review](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/56382/27054) in responsive design on my Android using Chrome

[image]

As you can see, it's pretty much uneditable using portrait mode.

Then, after testing to edit the question without being in the Review queue

[image]

---

Note that this doesn't happen in other communities like Stack Overflow... also to note that in other communities I don't have the same privileges that I have here (not sure if that'd have an impact too).

It could be as well that someone already edited it previously.

Comment: Looks like the same bug as I reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360266/295232) (but mine was in the Reopen Votes review queue). Staff (and myself) weren't able to reproduce it though.

Comment: @Glorfindel yes, that's the same and I also couldn't reproduce (only in that same answer)... Through comparing both one might be able to extract a pattern